# How to iterate over React children and access their ref in a helper function with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I am trying to learn how to perform more complex browser animations and would like to experiment with the FLIP methodology. I found this blog post https://medium.com/ft-product-technology/animating-list-reordering-with-react-hooks-1aa0d78a24dc that achieves an affect very similar what I want but I cannot work out how to translate the `calculateBoundingBoxes` helper function into TypeScript.

Attempting to access `child.ref` has the TypeScript error:

```
Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactPortal'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

How do I correctly type this function such that it only accepts children that all have refs?

```
const calculateBoundingBoxes = (children: ReactNode) => {
  const boundingBoxes = {};

  React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
    if (child == null) {
      throw new Error()
    }

    const domNode = child.ref.current;
    const nodeBoundingBox = domNode.getBoundingClientRect();

    boundingBoxes[child.key] = nodeBoundingBox;
  });

  return boundingBoxes;
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here, my solution :

```
type ElementWithRef = React.ReactElement & { ref?: React.RefObject<HTMLElement> };
```

```
const calculateBoundingBoxes = (children: ElementWithRef[]) => {
  const boundingBoxes: { [key: React.Key]: DOMRect | undefined } = {};

  React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
    if (!child || !child.key || !child.ref) {
      throw new Error();
    }

    const domNode = child.ref?.current;
    boundingBoxes[child.key] = domNode?.getBoundingClientRect();
  });

  return boundingBoxes;
};
```

`children` must be typed with ref.